# Accessing Salesforce session via oAuth maintains session across browsers

Tags: security, oauth2, session, browser, refresh-token

I am using oAuth 2.0 Web server flow to connect to Salesforce org and get the Access token and refresh token. I use the following URL to access a visualforce page that resides within the Salesforce org:

https://cs8.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=00DL0000002A1Dy!ARkAQA6b0UkJGIM2H8d9gE3hLNDDcFFegtkhslGSLEubFMeq2tslh714Ox2W0UilCt4w1223344444jxoNhf6dmMhdnXc&retURL=%2Fapex%2Ftestpage

I am able to sign in using this URL and this session ID across multiple browsers (same network and different network). My page contains sensitive client information and I would not want to allow multiple client browsers to use this same session ID to access the page. If a different browser is trying to access the page, I would want the client to request for a different session ID.

How do I handle this?

Thanks!